# With an Elastic Beanstalk load balancer, can my Node.js instance be notified that it's GOING to be terminated?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I know there are some lifecycle events that occur, but is there any way for an instance to know that it's slated for termination? My app is written in `node.js` if that matters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no out-of-the-box mechanism** for that. You would have to construct it yourself, which would not be that complicated. But it would have to involve  [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

You can setup a **CloudWatch Event rule** to trigger a lambda when your Lifecycle Hooks emits `autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING` event.

Now depending on exactly what you are trying to achieve on your instance, your lambda would have to send notification to the instance that its in terminating state.

Commonly this is done by using [SSM Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html). Using this service, the lambda would send command to the instance. SSM Agent running on the instance (assuming you set up your instances to work with SSM) would execute the command.

However, since you already have a web application running, maybe easier would be  for the lambda to perform **GET or POST HTTP** on your application. You could create a new endpoint on it, e.g. `/terminating` and the lambda would simply call it as a notification of pending termination.

Comment: Awesome. That helps a lot. But if I sent a POST, the load balancer would determine which instance to send that request to. I would then have to figure out how to run something in the dying instance

Comment: @Shamoon Run command seems as more suited solution then. Just have a look at how it works. May find it useful.